# Extending striping (alternating background colors) for line items in Netsuite PDF templates

Tags: html, css, netsuite, freemarker, bfo

In Netsuite, the #list loop for the item table will only render as many line items as there are number of of items. For example, if there's two items in a Sales Order, there will be only two line items in the PDF template as rendered by this example code:

```
<#if record.item?has_content>
<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%;"><!-- start items -->
    <#list record.item as item>
    <#if item_index==0>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th align="center" colspan="1">${item.quantity@label}</th>
        <th align="center" colspan="2">${item.item@label}</th>
        <th align="center" colspan="3">${item.description@label}</th>
        <th align="center" colspan="1">Unit Price</th>
        <th align="center" colspan="1">U/M</th>
        <th align="center" colspan="1">${item.amount@label}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</#if>
    <tr> <!--Move itemtable row up slightly to remove white space-->
        <td align="right" colspan="1">${item.quantity}</td>
        <td colspan="2"><span class="itemname">${item.item}</span></td>
        <td colspan="3">${item.description}</td>
        <td align="right" colspan="1">${item.rate?string.currency}</td>
        <td align="center" colspan="1">${item.units}</td>
        <td align="right" colspan="1">${item.amount?string.currency}</td>
    </tr>
</#list><!-- end items -->
</table>
</#if>
```

I have been following this official documentation for adding striping to line items in PDF templates https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N2866065.html

Whereupon you add this to  of the items:

```
<tr style="background-color: ${((item_index % 2)==0)?string('#ffffff', '#ccffcc')};">
```

**I need to extend the #list loop so a few "empty" rows *with alternate striping* are added to the bottom of the line item table**:

[Striping of line items with alternate background colors + extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3aXO.png)

My use case has different number of line items for each order, otherwise I would just hard code three alternate colored rows myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add some extra items to the list like `<#list record.item + [{}, {}, {}] as item>`. Then you need an `#if` that checks if `item?has_content`, and if not, then render a `<tr>` with one big spanning `td`, (unless in reality you need to handle null `item.quantity`, etc., in which case you don't need this extra `#if`).

As of using `%` for coloring, I don't know how many years the Netsuite FreeMarker is behind (except that a lot), but for a long time there's a feature like `${item?item_cycle('#ffffff', '#ccffcc', '#ffccff')` in FreeMarker. If they don't yet have `?item_cycle`, then I suggest writing a `#function` that returns the color code based on `item_index` (and that function will use `index % 3` and `#if`-`#elseif`-`#else`, and `#return` inside).

Another possibility is just maintaining a counter yourself, so it can be independent of `#list`. Like `<#assign rowCount = 0>`, and then before each item you do `<#assign rowCount++>`. But I guess extending the list with empty items is nicer.

Comment: Thank you @ddekany. I am still new so translating what you said into a code snippet is pretty hard for me. But I will try it out! This is a use case that comes up over and over again.